# Finding this operator's spectrum

Tags: real-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, compact-operators

In [an exam](http://www.matapp.unimib.it/~stefanom/didattica/matematica/anSup2014-2015/esami/esempio/esempio.pdf), my professor gave the following exercise:

> State and prove the spectral theorem for compact operators. Let $K$ be the operator defined by:
>
> $$Kf(t)=\int_0^1\min(t,s)f(s)\mathrm{d}s.$$
>
> (i) Show $K$ is a bounded operator from $L^2([0,1])$ to itself;
>
> (ii) Show $K$ is a compact and self-adjoint operator;
>
> (iii) Determine the spectrum of $K$; is the point 0 an eigenvalue?
>
> (iv) Calculate the operator norm of $K$.

Apart from wondering whether he meant compact self-adjoint operators or wanted statement and proof of the properties of the spectrum, i.e. 0 being an element and there being only a finite number of finite-multiplicity eigenvalues of $K$ outside any disk centered at 0, I can handle the proof part. This is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator, so we analyze the kernel. We show it is $L^2([0,1]^2)$ as follows:

\begin{align*}
\int_{[0,1]^2}\min(t,s)^2\mathrm{d}s\mathrm{d}t={}&\int_0^1\int_0^1\min(t,s)^2\chi_{t\leq s}(s)\mathrm{d}t\mathrm{d}s+{} \\
&{}+\int_0^1\int_0^1\min(t,s)^2\chi_{s\leq t}(s)\mathrm{d}s\mathrm{d}t={} \\
{}={}&\int_0^1\int_0^st^2\mathrm{d}t\mathrm{d}s+{} \\
&{}+\int_0^1\int_0^ts^2\mathrm{d}s\mathrm{d}t={} \\
{}={}&\int_0^1\frac{s^3}{3}\mathrm{d}s+\int_0^1\frac{t^3}{3}\mathrm{d}t={} \\
{}={}&\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{12}=\frac16.
\end{align*}

So the operator is both compact and bounded, and has operator norm at most $\frac16$. The kernel is evidently real and symmetric w.r.t. variable swapping, hence the operator is self-adjoint.

But how do I find the spectrum? How do I show 0 is(n't) an eigenvalue? And how can I find the spectral norm? I tried producing an eigenvector for zero, and should have proved monomials, $\sin(2\pi kx)$ and $\cos(2\pi kx)$ are not. So now I am a bit at a loss. I tried supposing $Kf=0$ and ended up with the following:

$$\int_0^tsf(s)\mathrm{d}s+t\int_t^1f(s)\mathrm{d}s=0,$$

for all $t\in[0,1]$. Now what? Then I tried using monomials to get the norm as being exactly the norm of the kernel. So I normalized $s^n$ in $L^2$, getting $\sqrt{2n+1}s^n$. I plugged that into $K$ and got $\frac{\sqrt{2n+1}}{n+1}t[1-\frac{t^{n+1}}{(n+1)(n+2)}$. Then I plugged this into wolfram, and got [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate(sqrt(2n%2B1)%2F(n%2B1)+*+t*%5B1-t%5E(n%2B1)%2F(n%2B1)(n%2B2)%5D)%5E2dt), which evalued at $t=1$ gives [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((2+x%2B1)+(-(2+(x%5E2%2B3+x%2B2))/(x%2B4)%2B((x%2B2)%5E2)/(2+x%2B5)%2B1/3+(x%2B1)%5E2))/(x%2B1)%5E4). Now the minimum appears to be 0, but then again it is attained for $n=-\frac12$ which gives $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\notin L^2$, so at least this is good to go. But calculating that max gave me something around 0.3, which is more than $\frac16$ which I calculated for the norm of the kernel. So have I miscalculated something? And how do I find that spectrum?

Comment: Hint: $K$ is the covariance function of a standard Brownian motion $\{B_t :t\in[0,1]\}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is clear that $0$ is in the spectrum of $K$, since $K$ is compact. Let us address if it is an eigenvalue: if $$ Kf=0,$$ this means we have 
$$\tag{1}
0=t\int_t^1f(s)\,ds+\int_0^ts\,f(s)\,ds.
$$
Differentiating (via [Lebesgue's Differentiation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem)), 
$$\tag{2}
0=\int_t^1 f(s)\,ds-tf(t)+tf(t)=\int_t^1f(s)\,ds,\ \ \ \text{a.e.}.
$$ Then, for any $v,t\in[0,1]$,
$$
\int_t^vf(s)\,ds=\int_t^1f(s)\,ds-\int_v^1f(s)\,ds=0.
$$
Applying Lebesgue's differentiation again, we get that $f(t)=0$ a.e. It follows that $0$ is not an eigenvalue.

For the nonzero part of the spectrum: since $K$ is compact, all nonzero elements of the spectrum are eigenvalues. Assume that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue: then
$$\tag{3}
\lambda f(t)=t\int_t^1f(s)\,ds+\int_0^ts\,f(s)\,ds.
$$ 
The right-hand-side of $(3)$ is continuous, so $f$ is continuous. But, knowing that $f$ is continuous, the right-hand side is differentiable; so $f$ is differentiable. Repeating the reasoning, we get that $f$ is infinitely differentiable. If we differentiate $(3)$, we get
$$\tag{4}
\lambda f'(t)=\int_t^1 f(t)\,ds-tf(t)+tf(t)=\int_t^1 f(t)\,ds.
$$
Differentiating once again, 
$$\tag{5}
\lambda f''(t)=-f(t).
$$ The solution to this DE is 
$$\tag{6}
f(t)=\alpha\,\cos\frac{t}{\sqrt\lambda}+\beta\,\sin\frac{t}{\sqrt\lambda}.
$$

Putting this $f$ into $(3)$, [we get](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=t++int_t%5E1+(a++cos(s%2Fsqrt(l))%2B+b++sin(s%2Fsqrt(l)))+ds%2Bint_0%5Et+(a+cos(s%2Fsqrt(l))%2B+b++sin(s%2Fsqrt(l)))+s+ds), after simplifying,
$$
0=\alpha t\sqrt\lambda\sin\frac1{\sqrt\lambda}+\beta t\sqrt\lambda\cos\frac1{\sqrt\lambda}-\alpha\lambda.
$$
Evaluating at $t=0$, we get $\alpha=0$. So the equation will be satisfied when $\beta\ne0$ and for every $t>0;$ thus
$$
\cos\frac1{\sqrt\lambda}=0.
$$
This forces $$\frac1{\sqrt\lambda}=\frac\pi2+k\pi,$$ so the eigenvalues are 
$$
\lambda_k=\frac4{(2k+1)^2\pi^2},\ \ k\in\mathbb N.
$$

---

Finally, for the operator norm: since $K$ is selfadjoint, we have 
$$
\|K\|=\sup\{|\lambda|:\ \lambda\in\sigma(K)\}=\sup\left\{\frac4{(2k+1)^2\pi^2}:\ k\in\mathbb N\right\}=\frac4{9\pi^2}.
$$

Comment: From the equation right after (2), should we not get $-f(t)+f(v)=0$ for a.e. $t,v$, and hence, for some $v_0$, $f(t)=f(v_0)$ a.e., hence $f$ is a.e. constant? How do we get it is zero a.e.?

Comment: I have no idea how you get to that conclusion (if you did, though, you immediately get $f=0$ since $0=\int_t^1f(s)ds$). The equation after (2) says that $\int_v^t f(s)ds=0-0=0$.

Comment: Whoops. I differentiated one integral in that eq w.r.t. $t$ and one w.r.t. $v$. I must instead differentiate both w.r.t. $t$, so the second one just vanishes and I'm left with $-f(t)=0$ a.e..

Comment: Oh, now I understand what you were doing. Well, good thing you got it :)

Comment: There was a typo with the eigenvalues, and it made me calculate the norm wrong, it is corrected now. I noticed it because it contradicted your estimate for the Hilbert-Schmidt norm.